# On true condition of free shipping don't show other methods in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have implemented free shipping with minimum order order 40.00 and also flat shipping for when free shipping not apply but when free shipping case true then it is shipping all methods.but i need only free shipping there.

On true condition of free shipping don't show other methods in magento , kindly help me how to do here is my site link
http://rainegoh.com/meirenstudio/index.php/

I am not aware of magento code

Answer (score 0):

The shipping restriction feature is not available in magento by default.

You must buy extension to achieve this. However as a quick fix for your situation you can edit the file packageName\Themename\template\checkout\cart\shipping.phtml

Place this code replacing the current one. I have explained the coding logic in comments. Don't forget to check it. Also use the same in MUlti-shipping method, if you are using it.

```
<dl class="sp-methods">
        <?php
        //precheck if the shipping method list has freeshipping in it.
        //if yes create a flag true. 
        foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $codes => $_ratess): 
        $methodCodes[]= $codes;
        endforeach; 
        $customFlag = in_array('freeshipping',$methodCodes);
        ?>
            <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
            <?php if(($customFlag)&&($code=='freeshipping'))  /* check for flag and filter freeshiping method. */
            {
             ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </label>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
                <?php } elseif(!$customFlag){ /* if flag is not true allow all method to show. */ ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </label>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php } endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
```